# Decrypting GPG files

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, restore, gnupg

I had to reinstall Ubuntu 18.4 on my machine and did not understand the secret key encryption when I had backed up my machine beforehand. Now it appears I have no secret key to decrypt and restore my files.

I know I can create a new key for myself, and I'm trying to figure out if i can use the new key, overriding the old one somehow? I'm getting the passphrase correct, but there is no key to match it with.

Also, since i'm the only user on this machine, i really don't care if I can somehow "hack" into the files to decrypt them or strip away the encryption. I really need my data, and simultaneously I got locked out of my Google account and cannot access my Drive, which has the same files. Google won't reset my password even though I've proven it's my account.

When i restore through Deja-dup, I get the following errors:

```
GPGError: GPG Failed, see log below:
===== Begin GnuPG log =====
gpg: WARNING: "--no-use-agent" is an obsolete option - it has no effect
gpg: failed to create temporary file '/home/tanusgreystar/.gnupg/.#lk0x000055a83f6427b0.tanusgreystar-Latitude-E6420.20815': Permission denied
gpg: keyblock resource '/home/tanusgreystar/.gnupg/pubring.kbx': Permission denied
gpg: AES256 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=0b)
gpg: [don't know]: invalid packet (ctb=47)
gpg: WARNING: encrypted message has been manipulated!
gpg: [don't know]: indeterminate length for invalid packet type 13
gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/tanusgreystar/.gnupg'
===== End GnuPG log =====
```

I get the same invalid packet errors, etc when I try to restore as root also. I just realized the log I posted shows the result of trying to restore as user.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your best avenue looks like begging to Google. [GPG keys cannot be re-generated, by design.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191767/is-it-possible-to-recover-a-secret-key-from-a-gpg-public-key) Sorry about your files.

Comment: Google won't make any exceptions, unfortunately. Thanks though.